# The perfect definition of impossible

Tags: logic

When i think about the true impossible, for me is a very dark area, that causes depression, because when we think about this simple question that begins whit, an example, "God creates the Human species", and we start asking "who made God?".

Here is where it becomes very complicated in my mind, i cant find an end, and even if we evolve to the point of finding an end, there's always another end.

And that is scary, lets say "John made God", then "who made John?", and if we think about this deep enough, its the perfect definition of impossible, you just cant find the true answer, because nothing comes from nothing everything is created from something, but that something as to come from something too, this  blows my mind.

And as a human, life starts losing it value, because i see everything whit that impossibility, sometimes i feel like i'm the only human, that sees how scary is that, because theirs no answer.

But then, what in the world are we doing here playing monkeys in a box, and people just see life as, job, get married, kids, and die happy, some close themselves in religions, somes in science, but in the end that is just it, we are all wasting time, so that we can die, and maybe, find our "time" answer for this impossibility, so that the next generations, starts the next quest for their impossibility.

Where can i find books whit this type of subject?

Comment: "... there's always another end." How do you know this? Has someone "visited" every possible "end" and told you what they found? "nothing comes from nothing everything is created from something" _Again_ an unfounded metaphysical declaration... Maybe you can draw the line at only saying things that you have sufficient reason to believe (question _how_ do you know things). - However if you are much troubled by such thoughts, I suggest looking into one or more of the mystical/religious traditions. After all, some of these traditions have stood the test of time for the greatest spectrum of people.

Comment: Many of us waste our time. Some of us spend our time productively. Newton, Mozart, Picasso to name three. Get to work. Or not. It's entirely up to you. You have one life. It's yours. You are in charge of it. Only you can answer your question. Why does one person end up living in the street and another ends up being Warren Buffet? Does anybody have any idea? I don't. Some people have more ambition than others. As far as the infinite regress, consider the integers ..., -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ... So perhaps causes are like that. Each cause has a preceding cause, but there is no first cause.

Comment: @user4894 picasso may be raising the bar too high. this is an existential question i think, but not researched enough to upvote. i would suggest finding love or whatever for others

Comment: @another_name Newton wasn't much of a lover. On his deathbed he said the accomplishment that brought him the greatest pride was keeping his virginity. Very strange dude. Picasso on the other hand was quite a famous lover. He painted and screwed all his life. Perhaps love and accomplishment are orthogonal, not mutually exclusive. You can have one or both or neither, one doesn't preclude the other. ps -- https://medium.com/@denislesak/why-isaac-newton-died-a-virgin-192decd2a750 says the deathbed story is "alleged," perhaps it's just folklore.

Comment: thanks, that's helpful @user4894 (i've had many existentially related pangs before)

Comment: About the lacking of meaning in (human) life, see Camus and Existentialism.

Comment: i wish i could edit this into something that works for the site... you sound like a western buddhist btw (no offence meant!)